# Delete a Git Branch and disable the restore Button

Tags: github

After working on a branch, i pushed the branch to GitHub and later i realized that i have pushed a token also which should not be visible to anyone. But now as the env file is in the GitHub, I deleted the branch from there so that no one could see it,

I tried to do

1. git branch -D  in my local
2. I deleted the branch from GitHub Website using the UI

Now  I want the branch to be permanently deleted and no one can restore it even. Is there anything i could do so that the history is deleted for that branch and we should not have ability to restore it.

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer:** 
Once you delete a branch which from remote (and it's not merged), its commits are gone. If you delete a branch locally, the associated commits will remain accessible until git's next garbage collection cycle runs.

*Read on if you're not bored* -

Just to confirm that the branch has been deleted from remote, you can run

```
git push origin --delete branchName
```

This will delete the branch from remote if it hasn't been deleted already.

Now, provided that your branch is not merged with any other branch, if you delete a branch, the commits associated will loose their pointer. The commits won't be deleted immediately but they will remain there without a pointer (pointer == branch). These commits are called as dangling commits.

So, the commit that contains your token is dangling now once the associated branch is deleted. Any one cloning your repo won't have access to the commit, but the commit will stay there on your system until git's next garbage collection cycle runs. And will be accessible to you with `git reflog`.

Once git's gc is run, it will clean up all dangling commits and they won't be accessible to you any more by any means.